# Why do I not get a p-value and F value from ANOVA in R?

Tags: r, anova

I am asked to determine using an appropriate test whether the internal concentration of isoleucine is statistically different between appropriate experiments. So I constructed a data frame in R as follow:

```
dat <- data.frame(experiment = c('no glu', 'glu', 'gluFCCP', 'gluV', 'gluN', 'gluNV'),internal_concentration = c(2.38, 8.57, 3.42, 6.17, 4.58,3.51)) 
print(dat)
experiment     internal_concentration
1     no glu                   2.38
2        glu                   8.57
3    gluFCCP                   3.42
4       gluV                   6.17
5       gluN                   4.58
6      gluNV                   3.51
```

I chose to perform an ANOVA test:

```
model<-lm(dat$internal_concentration~dat$experiment)

anova(model)

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: dat$internal_concentration
               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
dat$experiment  5 25.558  5.1117               
Residuals       0  0.000
```

I need the F and p values to determine if there's a significant difference, but this result is not working. How should I interpret this error and any suggestion on how to change the code/method?

Comment: Your model is saturated, so the MSE can't be estimated.

Comment: I just googled it, but still don't quite get it. Can you explain why this model is saturated, please?

Comment: If you need help choosing an appropriate test for your data, you should instead ask for help at [stats.se]. Though if you just have one observation per group I'm not sure even statistics will help you there. You'd need some very strong modeling assumption. But Stack Overflow isn't the right site to discuss that.

Comment: Will definitely check out this website, thanks for the help!

Comment: Please don't just cross-post. Instead, flag your question for moderator attention and request migration.